# group of diffeomorphisms of interval is perfect

Tags: group-theory, smooth-manifolds, foliations

Every element in $\mathrm{Diff}([0,1])$, group of diffeomorphisms of interval fixing the endpoints, can be written as a product of commutators since this group is perfect (I don't know the proof though).

Is it possible to write every element as just one commutator?

Edit: @Jim Belk I'm confused actually. The motivation for this question was this statement ,which I've seen in a paper in a peer reviewed journal(without proof though): If S is a surface with boundary which is not compact planar, and $b$ is a boundary component and $\mu$ is a diffeomorphism of the interval, then there is a foliation of $S \times [0,1]$ (we can think about it as a fiber bundle over S with fiber [0,1]), transverse to [0,1] factor, such that it has holonomy $\mu$ on boundary $b$. I've considered the case that S is a once punctured torus because it implies the general case. Now if we look at representation of fundamental group into group of diffeomorphisms of the fiber ([0,1] here) then this implies that $\mu$ can be written as a commutator in the diffeomorphism group and these two statements are equivalent. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I meant perfect not simple but I can't edit my post!

Comment: Edited. (You should be able to edit though)

Comment: @john seems website didn't recognize me as an existing user and made a new profile for me which I don't have access to it. Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 7):

It is not true that this group is perfect.  In particular, the function $D\colon \mathrm{Diff}([0,1])\to \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
D(f) \;=\; \bigl(\log f'(0),\log f'(1)\bigr)
$$
is a nontrivial homomorphism from $\mathrm{Diff}([0,1])$ onto an abelian group.

It turns out that the commutator subgroup of $\mathrm{Diff}([0,1])$ is precisely the kernel of this homomorphism.  See the following paper:

[Fukui, Kazuhiko. “Homologies of the group $\mathrm{Diff}^\infty (\textbf{R}^n, 0)$ and its subgroups”. *Journal of Mathematics of Kyoto University* 20, no. 3 (1980): 475–487.](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250522211)

Comment: That was a beautiful answer, Thanks Jim Belk. Unfortunately for some reason that I don't know I can't accept your answer or edit my question. However I made a mistake in writing the question, I should have said conjugacy classes of diffeomorphisms of interval(although this question as it is now and the answer is very interesting in my opinion as well, but I need the answer for conjugacy classes since I'm working with foliations). Is the answer different for that? Should I ask it as a separate question since I can't edit this one?

Comment: @Mehdi: Yes, if the current question was not what you intended, just make a new question.

Comment: Actually I am confused about your answer, and added something to the question as a note. @Jim Belk

Comment: @Medhi In answer to your question above, there must be something you're missing, but I can't tell from the information you've provided.  It's quite trivial that the function $D$ above is an epimorphism, so there must be something wrong in your argument from the paper.  If you start a new question with more details from your argument, I'm sure someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @JimBelk Thanks Jim, I've asked a new question and explained that in more detail here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323251/suspension-foliations-on-thickened-surfaces It would be great if you could take a look at that.