# suspension foliations on thickened surfaces

Tags: topological-groups, smooth-manifolds, foliations

I've seen this statement without proof in a peer reviewed journal and I'm looking for a proof:

"If $L$ is an oriented surface with boundary($\neq D^2$), and $C$ is a designated boundary component, then one can foliate $L \times I$($I$ an interval) with an arbitrary suspension homeomorphism on $C \times I$, and a foliation conjugate to the product foliation on $(\partial L - C)\times I$, provided that $L$ is either non-compact or has positive genus."

Note: Here was what I tried for proving it(which didn't work): Since suspension foliations are in one to one correspondence to their holonomy representation in diffeomorphism group of the fiber, so I should say that there exist a representation $\rho : \pi_1(L) \rightarrow Diff^+([0,1])$ such that $\rho$ sends the designated boundary component to $\mu$ where $\mu$ is an arbitrary suspension homeomorphism. Now consider the case where $L$ is a once punctured compact torus(compact surface of genus one with one boundary component), so its fundamental group has a representation of the form $\pi_1(L)\simeq <C , a, b \vert aba^{-1}b^{-1}=C>$ So this means that every element $\mu \in Diff^+([0,1])$ can be written as a commutator in $Diff^+([0,1])$ which means in particular this group is perfect which is false as Jim Belk gave a proof here: [group of diffeomorphisms of interval is perfect](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322085/group-of-diffeomorphisms-of-interval-is-perfect)
So I don't know what part is missing in my argument.

Comment: what is the full reference where you found this?

Comment: @WillJagy It's "taut foliations of 3-manifolds and suspensions of S^1"

Comment: I am not familiar at all with these topics, I just looked up the definitions, but I have the impression that you suppose the foliation on $L \times I$ (whose existence is claimed in the article) to be a suspension foliation too, that is given by some action of $\pi_1(L)$ on $\tilde{L} \times Diff^{+}(I)$. Perhaps you just proved that when $L \simeq T^2 \backslash \{\ast\}$, then the 'global foliation' is not a suspension?

Comment: downloadable at http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIF/AIF_1992__42_1-2/AIF_1992__42_1-2_193_0/AIF_1992__42_1-2_193_0.pdf

Comment: @JordanPayette Yes, that's what I assumed actually.